# Where to put entity 'helper functions'?

Tags: symfony

I am having trouble understand a key concept of Symfony 2.

I am working on a website where users can create content which then can be sent to other people, using a secret url. Something like www.yoursite.com/{secret-identifier-string}.

I plan on doing this as follows:

- Persist the user's content.
- Create the identifier string containing the content id and the creation timestamp (or any other content which will never change again, as extra safety feature) with a two-way encryption method (like `mcrypt_encrypt`).
- Create the link and display it to the user to give it away
- Whenever a url is called, the identifier string will be decrypted. If the provided timestamp matches the corresponding value of the content id row, the page will be displayed.

My questions are:

- Would you consider this a good procedure in general?
- Outside Symfony2 I would create helper methods like `getIdentifierString()` and `getContentPageLink()`. Where do I put the corresponding code in Symfony2? Does it belong inside the entity class? If so I am having problems because I am using a service class for encryption. The service is only available in the controller.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the identifier have to be a two-way encrypted string? Why not just generate a long random string (a one-way hash of the content even) and store that as an index? What's the reason/advantage for encrypting and decrypting the ID and timestamp?

Comment: I see an advantage in not generating unnecessary data which has to be stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that you create "helper classes" rather than "helper functions". Those classes may have dependencies on other classes in which case you'll define them as a service.

It sounds like your methods do have dependencies (on encryption) so you can make a new service that is responsible for generating links. In it's constructor it would take the encryptor and the methods would be passed the entity to generate a link/string for.

for example, your service:

```
<service id="app_core.linkifier" class="App\CoreBundle\Linkifier">
    <argument type="service" id="the.id.for.encryptor"/>
</service>
```

and class:

```
class Linkifier
{
    private $encryptor;

    public function __construct(Encryptor $encryptor)
    {
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    }

    public function generateContentPageLink(Entity $the_entity)
    {
        return $this->encryptor->encrypt($the_entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With all due respect to DI and service oriented design, namespacing and all the good stuff we benefit from,

I still refuse to type or read:

```
$this->mysyperfancyservice->dowhatevertheseviceissupposedtodowith($the_entity);
```

where a simple

```
do($the_entity);
```

is all I need on 150 instances across my project, where `do` is something everyone working on the project will know about.

That is what helper is meant for - readability and simplicity. As long as it doesn't depend on other services though.

My solution for that is in basic Composer feature:

    `"autoload": {
        ...
        "files": [ "src/helper/functions.php" ]
    }`

I put a very limited number of extremely useful functions in `src/helper/functions.php` file, and add it to project like that.

In order for the function to become available project-wide, it is required to run:

`composer dump-autoload`